# how to handle http 400 and 401 error while using webclient to download JSON

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am using an api that returns an error 400 if URL is invalid and error 401 if daily qouta is exhausted by 50%. it also returns the json but am not able to download this json as an exception occurs if these error occurs. the api am using is 
http://www.sharedcount.com/documentation.php

the code am using write now is...

```
private void _download_serialized_json_data(Uri Url)
        {
            var webClient = new WebClient();
                var json_data = string.Empty;
                // attempt to download JSON data as a string
                try
                {
                    webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
                    webClient.DownloadStringAsync(Url);
                }
                catch (Exception) { }

        }

void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            String Json = null;       

            try
            {
                Json = e.Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            if(Json!=null)
            {
                data=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(Json);
                result.Text = "facebook : "+data.Facebook.like_count+"\nGooglePlus : "+data.GooglePlusOne;
            }
            else 
            {
                result.Text = "Invald URL \nor you exceeded your daily quota of 100,000 queries by 50%.";

            }

        }
```

currently am showing both errors if exception occurs. but i want to download the json and display that. how should i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the response content, you will need to use `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` instead. Install it from here: [Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http)

Then try this:

```
private async void Foo2()
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost/fooooo");
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
    HttpStatusCode statusCode = response.StatusCode; // E.g.: 404
    string reason = response.ReasonPhrase; // E.g.: Not Found
    string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // The response content.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```
void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        String Json = null;       

        if(e.Error != null)
        {
           //Some error occured, show the error message
           var ErrorMsg = e.Error.Message;
        }
        else
        {
          //Got some response .. rest of your code
          Json = e.Result;
        }

    }
```

Comment: no actually i want to know whether it was an error 400 or 401, or i want to read the json no matter what the error response was.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue using WebClient, I saw the error response stream being captured in Fiddler, but my .NET code was catching the exception and did not appear to be capturing the response stream.

You can read the Response stream from the WebException object to get the response data stream out.

```
using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    string response = "";
    try
    {
        response = client.UploadString(someURL, "user=billy&pass=12345");
    }
    catch(WebException ex)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string exResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(exResponse);
        }
    }
}
```